# Filling no data in raster using focal statistics in batch in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, con, focal-statistics

I know how to use the below python script to fill no data in a single raster using focal statistics, but I have a series of rasters, I do not want to run the script one by one.

Can any people tell me how to do it in batch?

```
>>>
... import arcpy

... from arcpy import env

... from arcpy.sa import *

... env.workspace = "C:/Users/wing/Desktop/try/NDVI"

... outCon = Con(Raster("MOD13Q1.A2000049.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif")<-2000, FocalStatistics("MOD13Q1.A2000049.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif",NbrRectangle(3,3),"MEAN","NODATA"), "MOD13Q1.A2000049.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif")

... outCon.save("C:/Users/wing/Desktop/try/outcon")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make a loop based on ListRasters in your repository. Note that your method is looking for "impossible NDVI values" (< -2000) but if you want to specifically manage NoData, then you should use "IsNull()". And if you have **values** below -2000, focal stat will not ignore them, so you should probably force those values to be NoData first. (e.g. with Con(myraster>-2000,myraster) )

```
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("MOD*", "TIF")
for modNDVI in rasters:
    inraster = Raster(modNDVI) #make a raster object from iput name
    outraster = modNDVI.replace("NDVI","NDVI_filled") #set an output name
    outCon = Con(IsNull(inraster), FocalStatistics(inraster,NbrRectangle(3,3),"MEAN","NODATA"), inraster)
    outCon.save(outraster)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried your code and there is an error shown below:    
 
Runtime error : Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<string>", line 10, in <module> AttributeError: 'Raster' object has no attribute 'Save'. I don't know how to fix it... hope for your reply.

Comment: sorry for the type, it save and not Save (case sensitive)

Comment: I have changed the code by                                                              
outraster = Con(inraster<-2000, FocalStatistics(inraster,NbrRectangle(3,3),"MEAN","NODATA"), inraster)
outraster.save(modNDVI.replace("NDVI","NDVI_filled")) and then it works, but I don't know whether it is right or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. Another question is that how can I output the filled raster to a different place? Hope for your reply.

Comment: there are different ways to manage your text in Python (modNDVI contains the  name of your file as a string). For instance, you can concacatenated a path with the name outCon.save( 'my/new/path/'  + outraster) you could also use os.walk for more control.